# How can you make multiple toggles for one accordion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accordion

I have a product feature map I'm trying to create. I was able to get the accordions working, but how can I make the "+" buttons on the product image also trigger the corresponding accordion?

https://jsfiddle.net/rza4hs16/1/

Here is some of my copied code from the jsfiddle:

```
<div class="accordion-toggle">
<div class="map-container">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/quhRUKx.jpg" width="500px">
<a id="map-marker-1" class="map-marker" href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
</div>
<div class="accordion-container">
  <div class="set">
    <a href="#">
   Accordion 1
      <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
    </a>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".set > a").on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
      $(this).removeClass("active");
      $(this)
        .siblings(".content")
        .slideUp(200);
      $(".set > a i")
        .removeClass("fa-minus")
        .addClass("fa-plus");
    } else {
      $(".set > a i")
        .removeClass("fa-minus")
        .addClass("fa-plus");
      $(this)
        .find("i")
        .removeClass("fa-plus")
        .addClass("fa-minus");
      $(".set > a").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
      $(".content").slideUp(200);
      $(this)
        .siblings(".content")
        .slideDown(200);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add and ID to the accordion

```
    <a href="#" id="acc1">
         Accordion 1
  <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</a>
```

You can then get the accordion object and call the click command from there from your + button

```
<a id="map-marker-1" class="map-marker" href="#" onclick='$("#acc1").click()'>
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ocwus17y/

Comment: Thank you! I've been toying around with this all day and I'm closing to having it the way I want. This was a huge help. My only other question is how to set the active status on the "+" as well. I have it set up here: https://jsfiddle.net/oz45ajq1/
I'm hoping that when either the "+" button is set or the accordion is clicked, it will update the corrisponding "+" and accordion to active. So if someone clicks on an accordion, the "+" would change and show the suer where that feature is on the product.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good opportunity to use a `data-` attribute. You can add user-defined properties to any DOM element this way.

```
<div class="accordion-toggle">
<div class="map-container">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/quhRUKx.jpg" width="500px">
<a id="map-marker-1" class="map-marker" href="#" data-feature="1" ><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
</div>
<div class="accordion-container">
  <div class="set" data-feature="1" >
    <a href="#">
   Accordion 1
      <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
    </a>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

And your JS:

```
$(".map-marker").click(()=>{
    $('.set[data-feature="' + $(this).attr('data-feature') + '"] > a').click();
});
```

Also, since it's better not to trigger code by emulating events, it would be good to move the accordion code out of the event handler into a separate function and have both event handlers call it.